# How to use WPF elements from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently developing a chat client/server with a WPF visual interface. One of the main function in the MainWindow class is designed to write a message in a richbox in the related WPF.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // VU Window
    public static MainWindow vuClient;

    // VU Initialization
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vuClient = this;
    }

    static public void writeChat(User pUser, String pMessage)
    {
        ...
        // Writing in the richbox
        vuClient.vuChatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(formatedMessage);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I call `writeChat()` in the `MainWindow()` function or through an event (`onclick` for example) everything works as attended, but if I try to call this function via an other class nothing happens! I don't even have an error. Do you have any clue about that issue?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the other class and step into it. Does it get into WriteChat()? If it does, hover over vuClient, vuChatBox, etc to see what is assigned and if they are expected.

Comment: You must be swallowing the exception. Are you calling it from another thread? (a timer for example)

Comment: @GrantWinney It's an other class called Core, the function is called like that : MainWindow.writeChat(...)

Comment: @Paul Yes it does! I tried to write some stuff like System.Console.WriteLine(vuClient.vuClient.text), and it actually worked, I saw the my placeholder text. I feel like it doesn't want to add text from an other class order.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing No I don't, the call comes from my Main()

Comment: Hmm.. I think we need to see more code.. (see the first comment)

Answer (score 0):

No need to maintain the object "vuClient". Because writeChat is a static method.

You can directly called like below

```
MainWindow.writeChat();
```

Comment: you can call like this.vuCharBox.Document.Blocks.Add(formatedMessage);

Answer (score 0):

you can't use an UI element or a function in some other class. you need to make a Delegate with an event. with the help of this event you can update your UI accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I'm going to try this way.

Comment: yeah sure you must cause i don't think there is any other way to do this. :) if you are using MVVM architecture then Binding UIelement with properties may help you too.